# Journey deployment between business units

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there an build-in feature to deploy Journeys between multiple business units?

If not, what are common ways to deploy journeys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically - no is the short answer.
This month's update however does offer Journey Templates, but I haven't found a method of saving a Journey as a template and sharing between BUs.

I have read rumour that the feature to copy a Journey between business units is on the horizon but no idea of the truth in this.

You can really only create journeys manually in each business unit. I typically create and document at the parent, and then create manually in the child BUs. A bit of a pain there isn't a feature to copy/paste a journey as it would make life easier.

Answer (score 5):

According to the April 2019 release notes, you will soon be able to 'use Deployment Manager to copy the design of the journey and deploy it in other business units or enterprises in Marketing Cloud'
You can check out this link for more information:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_april_2019_platform_deployment_manager.htm&type=5

Comment: Welcome Marco. Please do edit and post some of the relevant information directly here.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new feature with the last release that allows migrating Journeys between BUs. So that, it is necessary to install the package ‘[Deployment Manager](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FvMviUAF)’ from the Appexchange in all the BUs that will be involved in the migration (here you have the [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_deployment_manager.htm&type=5) to the documentation).

This functionality can help you to replicate journeys from the testing BU to the marketing one. The only thing to keep mind is that only the journey flow is migrated, not the configuration of each activity, but for sure it will save more time than starting to do it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pull out the journey into a JSON file via the REST endpoint  however you'll need to go through and edit portions to respect the changes between BUs, activities and DEs so depending on the size of the journey it might be easier to just recreate in the UI.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/journey-builder-api-overview.htm